# Validate Input DateTime C#

Tags: datetime, c#-3.0

How can I validate the `DateTime` (input) to be in format of `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM` in C#

I need to throw an error if the specified format doesn't match the above one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at using [DateTime.TryParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

> Converts the specified string
>   representation of a date and time to
>   its DateTime equivalent using the
>   specified format, culture-specific
>   format information, and style. The
>   format of the string representation
>   must match the specified format
>   exactly. The method returns a value
>   that indicates whether the conversion
>   succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) - this automatically throws FormatException if the input is not in specified format:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dtString, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```